# How to push to new View with Animation (Right to left) on Button click(Android)

Tags: android, animation, view

In android Application.

In One Activity, When user clicks on button then how to display new view with animation Right to Left?

[image]

So when user clicks on Forgot Password button as attached in screenshot then I want to show new view(new Layout) from activity.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is rather unclear what you want. Are you talking about a fragment or a new activity? Please try to add more info or draw an image so we can understand.

Comment: @Evilunclebill : I am talking about activity.Also attached screenshot.Please see my edit.